# returning array from function in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, codeblocks

this my program to return array from function in c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int *pTest(){
    static int a[] = {2,3,4,6,9};
    return a;
}

int main(){
    int *x;
    x = pTest();
    while(*x != NULL){
        cout << *x++ << "  ";
    }
}
```

according to me output should be `2  3  4  6  9`
but on my machine output is `2  3  4  6  9  1`,
why there is an extra `1` in the output.
i am using `codeblocks` ,gcc 4.8.1

Comment: Arrays don't have an implicit zero element. What would that mean if you had, say, `struct S {S(int);};` and an array of `S`?

Comment: You should use container classes (e.g. `std::vector` for dynamically sized or `std::array` for fixed size)

Comment: You don't tell the loop when to stop. It is only string literals that put a NULL character in automatically. Try: `static int a[] = {2,3,4,6,9,0};`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Arrays aren't zero-terminated, so the loop `while (*x != NULL)` will keep reading beyond the array until it finds a zero-valued word, or crashes, or causes some other undefined behaviour.

You'll either need to add a terminator to the array (if you can choose a value, perhaps zero, that won't be a valid array element), or return the length in some other way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a count and take the size of the array.
Like this:

```
int k = 0;
while(k <= sizeof(x)){
    cout  << "  "<< *x++;
    k++;

}
```

Comment: That is not correct. `sizeof(x)` will evaluate to `sizeof(int*)`. Not what you are expecting to find.

Answer (score 0):

With std::vector your function will be:

```
std::vector<int> ptest() {
    static const int a[] = {2,3,4,6,9};
    std::vector<int> vec (a, a + sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]) );
    return vec;
}
```